# While-loop freezing

Tags: java, while-loop, freeze

I'm currently making a paper-rock-scissors game where you play against the computer. My while-loop for controlling who's reached the maximum score keeps freezing. I hope the method below isn't too hard to read and has sufficient information. Basically when I play the game and try to make a move the program just freezes. I've tried the program without the while-loop and it works fine. I made it so every move is a number. 0 for rock, 1 for scissor and 2 for paper. The method computerPlayer.newChoice(); is a random-generated number from another class.

```
public void newChoice() {
    while (humanS < 3 && computerS < 3) {
        computerPlayer.newChoice();

        if (playerChoice == 0) {
            viewer.jLblHumanM.setText("Sten");
            if (computerPlayer.choice == 0) {
                viewer.jLblComputerM.setText("Sten");

            } else if (computerPlayer.choice == 1) {
                HScore += 1;
                viewer.jLblComputerM.setText("Sax");
                viewer.jLblHumanS.setText("" + HScore);
            } else if (computerPlayer.choice == 2) {
                CScore += 1;
                viewer.jLblComputerM.setText("Påse");
                viewer.jLblComputerS.setText("" + CScore);
            }
        } else if (playerChoice == 1) {
            viewer.jLblHumanM.setText("Sax");
            if (computerPlayer.choice == 0) {
                HScore += 1;
                viewer.jLblComputerM.setText("Sten");
                viewer.jLblHumanS.setText("" + HScore);

            } else if (computerPlayer.choice == 1) {
                viewer.jLblComputerM.setText("Sax");

            } else if (computerPlayer.choice == 2) {
                HScore += 1;
                viewer.jLblComputerM.setText("Påse");
                viewer.jLblHumanS.setText("" + HScore);
            }
        } else if (playerChoice == 2) {
            viewer.jLblHumanM.setText("Påse");
            if (computerPlayer.choice == 0) {
                viewer.jLblComputerM.setText("Sten");
                HScore += 1;
                viewer.jLblHumanS.setText("" + HScore);
            } else if (computerPlayer.choice == 1) {
                viewer.jLblComputerM.setText("Sax");
                CScore += 1;
                viewer.jLblComputerS.setText("" + CScore);
            } else if (computerPlayer.choice == 2) {
                viewer.jLblComputerM.setText("Påse");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if `(humanS < 3 && computerS < 3)` then you will keep calling `newChoice` for ever (and probably get a StackOverflowError at some point)...

Comment: I don't think you are incrementing your `humanS` or `computerS` variables...

Comment: What thread is executing this code?

Answer (score 0):

You have too many variables. humanS and HScore and compterS and CScore seem to be duplicative, as well as the source of your problem.

```
while(humanS < 3 && computerS < 3){
```

This should be

```
while(HScore < 3 && CScore < 3){
```

Comment: Yeah, sloppy mistake. But after changing my while-loop to -

 while(HScore < 3 && CScore < 3){
the program gives the one who wins the first move 3 points immediately.

Comment: @Bengan  Learning to use a debugger would help you to resolve both of these issues, and would be a better use of both of our times